# Unable to mock $root.$refs while unit testing Vue component

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I have a component where im using reference of $root in its mounted hook.

```
//here's mounted of my Vue component
mounted() {
    this.$root.$refs.myRef.show()
}
```

here is the test case

```
it('test mount', () => {
  shallowMount(myComponent)
})
```

But it is not getting the root's reference

```
//error
Could notresolve show() of undefined
```

I've tried to mock $root as well

```
it('test mount', () => {
  shallowMount(myComponent, {
    mocks: {
      $root: {
        $refs: {
          myRef: {
            show: jest.fn()
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
})
```

But still, it gives the same error.

Comment: Perhaps because `myRef` is not the same as `myref` ?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, that was a typo by mistakenly written while posting this question but in my code the `myRef` is same.

Comment: Please update with the entire test, as you don't seem to care much about syntax, but it matters greatly. For example, you also messed the syntax of the testing function: `it()` (a.k.a. `test()`) takes two params: test name and test handler. `it(name)(object)` will always break.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I've updated the test. Sorry for the syntax as I posted it by phone.